# Changing language to zendx_jquery_form_element_datepicker

Tags: zendx

I wonder if there a way to change the language in a `zendx_jquery_form_element_datepicker`, I mean, my page shows all in spanish, and when I show the element `datepicker` the days and months appear in english and I want them to appear in spanish.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the regional attribute for the datepicker element..

```
$dob= new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('dob');
$dob->setLabel('Date of Birth:')                    
            ->setJQueryParam('dateFormat', 'dd.mm.yy')
            ->setJqueryParam('regional', 'es')
```